# Apply BOTH BlendMode AND filter to same movieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, glow

Im trying to create a 'neon glow effect thru a combination of both BlendModes and glow filter

Problem is, they seem to cancel each other out if applied together...not having any luch doing this dynamically.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

- Apply `BlendMode` to your graphic
- Use `BitmapData`, and `draw()` your graphic so you get a new bitmap representation of it (pretty much what applying a blendmode or a filter will do anyway)
- Apply your `Filter` to this new `Bitmap`
- ???
- Profit